# Querying for values of embedded documents in MongoDB with PyMongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have a document in MongoDB that looks like this

```
{
    "_id": 0,
    "cash_balance": 50,
    "holdings": [
        {
            "name": "item1",
            "code": "code1",
            "quantity": 300
        },
        {
            "name": "item2",
            "code": "code2",
            "quantity": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to query for this particular document and get the quantity value of the object inside the **holdings** array whose **code** matches **"code1"**. It can be assumed that there will be a match.

```
data = collection.find_one({"_id": 0, "holdings.code": "code1"}, {"holdings.$.quantity": 1})
```

> > { "_id": 0, "holdings": [{"name": "item1", "code": "code1", "quantity": 300}] }

Running the above code gives me this output and I can get the quantity value by using:

```
data["holdings"][0]["quantity]
```

> > 300

However this seems to be a rather roundabout way of getting a single value. Is there a way I can query for the value of a particular key matching the code query without getting the holdings array containing the required object?

Answer (score 2):

try to use the aggregate method with $unwind.

$unwind does the following:

> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

[MongoDB documentation for $unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

I created a [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MsngI2MX_7Z) example for you.